# When using pointers to structs and using them between C++ and C#, do I need to delete the pointer?

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, dllexport

I have a program which uses C# and C++. C++ is used to do low level things such as rendering.
In C# I am making an Input class. It uses GLFW to get the mouse position:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Vector2* GetCursorPos()
{
    double xpos, ypos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(Window, &xpos, &ypos);

    Vector2* pos = new Vector2{ (float)xpos, (float)ypos };
    return pos;
}
```

Here is the Vector2 struct:

```
struct Vector2
{
    float X;
    float Y;
};
```

In the Input class:

```
[DllImport("Internal.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern unsafe Vector2* GetCursorPos();

public static unsafe (float x, float y) GetMousePosition()
{
    Vector2* pos = GetCursorPos();
    return (pos->X, pos->Y);
}
```

My question is, should I delete this `Vector2*`, (and where to do so) or is it not needed due to garbage collection in C#.

Comment: Yes, you would have to delete the struct when you are done with it, at the c++ side, Create an additional function `FreeCursorPos`

Comment: Or provide an api that passes something down to the C side for your function to fill in. Whoever creates something has the responsibility of making sure it gets torn down appropriately

Comment: Alternatively, you could do away with the struct and simply return the x and y pos `GetCursorPosition(float * xpos, float * ypos);` much in the same way as `glfwGetCursorPos`, no new and deletes required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using the struct you would have to delete it by creating another function on the c++ side, such as `FreeCursorPos`

Alternatively you could just return the x and y pos in the parameters like this:

In the c++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetCursorPos(float * outxpos, float * outypos)
{
    double xpos, ypos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(Window, &xpos, &ypos);

    *outxpos = (float)xpos;
    *outypos = (float)ypos;
}
```

Not only does this have the advantage that you don't need new and delete, but you no longer need to mark your c# as `unsafe`

```
[DllImport("Internal.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern void GetCursorPos(float * outxpos, float * outxpos);

public static (float x, float y) GetMousePosition()
{
    float outxpos;
    float outxpos;
    GetCursorPos(&outxpos, &outypos);
    return (outxpos, outypos);
}
```